# how to calculate required time from cycle time and quantity in c#

Tags: c#, timespan

i want to calculate required time to produce a batch of parts
in which i have cycle time and quantity of parts

cycleTime = time to produce a part in (sec).

so is it correct

```
        decimal rqtime = (CycleTime * oprQty)/3600;
        TimeSpan rts = TimeSpan.FromHours(Convert.ToDouble(rqtime));
        label8.Text = rts.ToString();
```

if not please give me some solution on that

and also i want to give notification to user when required time is completed
so how to do it in c#

Comment: what data type is `CycleTime` and `oprQty` ?

Comment: i used int data type for CycleTIme and oprQty

Comment: in this case you will have an integer division and lose information. That means that if for example `CycleTime = 100` and `oprQty = 10` then `rqtime` will be `0`! you can solve this my simply adding a `m` at the end of `3600` => `decimal rqtime = (CycleTime * oprQty)/3600m;`

Answer (score 2):

If I understand it correctly you can try it like this:

```
var CycleTime = 30; //seconds
var oprQty = 100; //number of parts
decimal rqtime = (CycleTime * oprQty);
TimeSpan rts = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Convert.ToDouble(rqtime));
label8.Text = string.Format("Time to complete {0}", rts);
//the label will show: Time to complete 00:50:00
```

Note that considering you have the cycle in seconds there is no need to divide it by 3600 and you can use the method `TimeSpan.FromSeconds` to properly convert those seconds into a duration.

**Update**

To notify the users you can use a `Timer` to do this:

```
var aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(rts.TotalMilliseconds); 
 //here you can use the same time span above.
aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
aTimer.Enabled = true; 

private void OnTimedEvent(Object source, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("The batch is completed!");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, so here's an answer:

You will get the right results with your code, but:

1. There is a use for the decimal type (if you need the precision), but if you're only using it to feed the TimeSpan.FromHours method and cast it right back to double, why not use double in the first place? **update:** That way, you also lose the integer-division correctly pointed out by Mong Zhu in the comments
2. Why devide by 3600 and use TimeSpan.FromHours if you can use TimeSpan.FromSeconds?

So I would do simply:

```
int cycleTime = 12;
int oprQty = 1000;

double rqtime = cycleTime * oprQty;
TimeSpan rts = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(rqtime);
label8.Text = rts.ToString();
```